# Convert enum to int inside HTML

Tags: razor

I have the following line

```
<div class="row" data-hns-target="salesChannel" data-hns-condition="^@Model.SeenSalesChannel$">
```

`Model.SeenSalesChannel` is an enumeration.  I would like to convert this to the corresponding int value but

```
<div class="row" data-hns-target="salesChannel" data-hns-condition="^@(int)Model.SeenSalesChannel$">
```

is not valid.  What else could I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in `()`

```
<div class="row" data-hns-target="salesChannel" data-hns-condition="^@((int)Model.SeenSalesChannel)$">
```